# How to stop showing the checkbox in the input of Material UI TextField with select attribute when we have MenuItems with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have added checkboxes to the MenuItems in the TextField of type `Select`. When I select one of the MenuItems, the checkbox is also displaying in the input of the TextField.

Req: I need to stop displaying the check box in the input of TextField.
I need to strictly use the TextField with Selcet attribute.

Can someone please help me with this? Thnak you.

[image]

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-06gns?file=/demo.js

code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
     }
  }
};

const names = ["Oliver Hansen", "Van Henry"];

export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks() {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

   const handleChange = (event) => {
   const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
     // On autofill we get a the stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <TextField
          // multiple
          select
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: material ui already provides checkbox select https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to use TextField with Select attribute only. The link is specifying to AutoComplete.

Answer (score 1):

I did give it a try and changed some code, onchange and renderValue should be props on select, on not textfield so it was not working

```
import * as React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;

const names = ["Oliver Hansen", "Van Henry"];

export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks() {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (!personName.includes(event.target.value))
      setPersonName(event.target.value); // selected options
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <TextField
          select
          SelectProps={{
            multiple: true,
            value: personName,
            onChange: (e) => handleChange(e),
            renderValue: (selected) => selected.join(", "),
            style: {
              width: "250px",
              maxHeight: `${ITEM_HEIGHT} * 4.5 + ${ITEM_PADDING_TOP}`
            }
          }}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={personName.includes(name)} />}
                label={name}
              />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please check working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-select-with-textfield-uf100

Comment: Thank you @Madhuri. I didn't know that renderValue can be placed inside the SelectProps. It really helped. :)

Comment: Great, I would appreciate if you mark it as a correct answer